# How to give permanent mic access to all sites in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

So I'm sick of being asked to confirm mic access-- the answer from me is always YES.

Yes I am aware of the privacy risk this poses.

So I'm in my Chrome User Data folder, in the Preferences file, and I see a list of sites that looks like this:

```
  "content_settings": {
     "clear_on_exit_migrated": true,
     "pattern_pairs": {
        "file:///Users/Aerovistae/Desktop/webspeech.html,*": {
           "media-stream-mic": 3
        },
        "http://cameroid.com:80,*": {
           "media-stream-camera": 1,
           "media-stream-mic": 1
        },
        "http://content.sierraclub.org:80,http://content.sierraclub.org:80": {
           "geolocation": 1
        },

     },
     "pref_version": 1
  },
```

And I'm guessing this media-stream bit might pertain to this. I'm trying to add one that's some variant of "*" to match every site but of course that's not working. Is this a viable approach and I'm just not quite there, or is there another way to do it, or is this impossible?